# ASP.NET Ajax Library

Tags: asp.net-ajax

while using the ASP.Net Ajax Library to load scripts does it check to see if the script is already loaded?

For example, if I have a script block in my aspx page and one in my master page and they both load jquery via the sys.require() method with jquery get loaded twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried it myself, but it 'should' be intelligent enough to only load once.

Here's a related article: [HOW TO Load Required Scripts](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/HOW%20TO%20Load%20Required%20Scripts.ashx), esp the last paragraph.

PS: Considering it is smart enough to combine scripts, it should be able to detect duplicates.